# Firebase database rules allowing to read deeper nodes by field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have items for each user with `privacy` field (see structure below). I need use a rule, that allows to owner user read all his items, but another users could read only items with privacy > 0 (0 means private item). So please help me create this rules.

My current rules doen't work, because it not allowing to read user's items using `getReference("items/{userUid}").addChildEventListener` in my Android app.

```
root   
 items
  {userUid}
   {itemUid}
     name: a
     privacy: 0     
   {itemUid}
     name: b
     privacy: 1
```

Rules:

```
"items": {
      "$uid": {
        "$itemUid": {
          ".read":  "$uid === auth.uid || data.child('privacy').val() > 0" 
        },
        ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're trying to read from `items/{userUid}`, but your rules are set to `items/{userUid}/{itemUid}`. You should remove that deeper child and keep your read rule at `{userUid}`:

```
"items": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read":  "$uid === auth.uid || data.child('privacy').val() > 0",
    ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

**Update 1:** Have in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). This means that a user can either read all data from that node, or not read any data at all. But your problem can be solved by using the [recently introduced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/introducing-query-based-security-rules.html) [Query-based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules).

You can keep the query you're using to **read the owner data**:

```
getReference("items/{userUid}").addChildEventListener
```

But when **reading data for the other users**, you'll need to filter it to show only the ones with `privacy>0`:

```
getReference("items/{userUid}").orderByChild('privacy').startAt(1).addChildEventListener
```

(`orderByChild('privacy').startAt(1)` is equivalent to `privacy>=1`)

And then you can add this query to your rules to make sure that this data is only read when using this query:

```
{
    "rules": {
    "items": {
        "$uid": {
            ".read":  "$uid == auth.uid || (query.orderByChild === 'privacy' && query.startAt === 1)",
            ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
            ".indexOn":["privacy"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've also added `.indexOn` to [improve performance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-child) when ordering the data by privacy.

**Update 2:** In order to access an item directly, you can use the following rules:

```
".read": "(auth != null && $uid === auth.uid) || (auth != null && query.orderByKey) || (auth != null && query.orderByChild === 'privacy' && query.startAt === '1')"
```

and access it using:

```
getReference(ref_to_items_userUid).orderByKey().equalTo(itemKey)
```

Comment: You are right, but in my case I need to get all child nodes of user except private nodes. I can&#39;t read child nodes one by one, because I don&#39;t know their ids.

Comment: Please post the query you're using for the owner and the query you're using for the other users.

Comment: You can find my query in the post: `getReference("items/{userUid}").addChildEventListener` — this using to get all items of user and subscribes to their changes

Comment: `".indexOn": "privacy"` should be without square brackets guess

Comment: Sure thing. The brackets are used for arrays of keys. When you'll be querying on multiple childs.

Comment: But one more thing: how can I get single item with this rules? My current call `getReference(ref_to_item).addValueEventListener` doesn't work now.

Comment: That's weird. I've tested that on my database and it works just find. Are you making this call on the Owner side?

Comment: Trying to make this call from Android app, signed in as Firebase user

Comment: So, succeed result of my test is following call: `getReference(ref_to_items_userUid).orderByKey().equalTo(itemKey)` with this rules: `"(auth != null && $uid === auth.uid) || (auth != null && query.orderByKey) || (auth != null && query.orderByChild === 'privacy' && query.startAt === '1')"`, so you can update your answer with this

Comment: Thank you, I've just updated my answer with that. :)

Comment: Please update you answer: `query.startAt >= 1` instead of `query.startAt === 1`